# commentaries on the book Derech Hashem

Tags: jewish-books, commentaries, ramchal

Title says it all. I am looking for commentaries published for the Ramchal's book Derech Hashem (if any exist)

Comment: Any and all? Or recommended ones? If the latter, then we'd first need to know your criteria for a good commentary.

Comment: @msh210 any or all. the more the better. good commentary - by qualified person. ideally talmid chacham. not some secular bible critic.

Comment: What about English translations? is that part of your quest?

Comment: @DannySchoemann no. thnx

Comment: You should probably add in that qualification (that is, no English).

Comment: @Lee i asked for commentaries. dont see how a translation fits that category. do you?

Comment: @ray I understood Danny's question to mean "an English translation of a commentary". Furthermore, some translations (e.g. The Stone Chumash) are indeed *based* on commentaries (in there case mostly that of RaSh"I).

Answer (score 5):

Three possibilities with the publishers' blurbs.

[Way of God: Derech Hashem (Torah Classics Library) (English and Hebrew Edition) Hardcover – November 1, 1981](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/087306769X) 
by Moshe Chaim Luzzatto (Author), Aryeh Kaplan  (Translator)

> Explores Divine regulation of the world. **With Rabbi Yosef Begun's
>   marginal notes.** Vowelized, facing Hebrew and English texts.

[Essentials; **A Commentary** on Derech Hashem by Rav Moshe Chaim Luzzato](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1600912222)  Hardcover – August 20, 2012
by Rebbetzin S. Feldbrand  (Author)

> As in her other books, Rebbetzin Feldbrand illuminates and clarifies
>   these and other difficult concepts and brings them within our reach.

[The Elucidated Derech Hashem. A Systematic Approach to the Basic Principles of Jewish Belief, 
by Rabbi Abba Zvi Naiman](http://www.feldheim.com/the-elucidated-derech-hashem.html)
New Interwoven Translation and **Commentary**

> Rabbi Abba Zvi Naiman expertly guides the reader with his clear and
>   accurate translation, interwoven with the Hebrew original, and
>   combines it with his extensive Zichron Eliyahu commentary, which
>   provides references and explores the Ramchal’s vast writings to reveal
>   the depth of his careful and precise language. This edition promises
>   to be a major English classic for the Torah world.

Comment: Having gone through the first third or so of Derekh HaShem with its commentary, I highly recommend *The Elucidated Derech Hashem* cited in the answer.